# SVG BeginElement does not reset the clock for animation

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I have the following code which works during loading of the document:

```
      <animate
        id="animation1"
        attributeName="opacity"
        from="0"
        to="0.5"
        dur="1s"
        begin="0s; 2s;"
        end="1s; 3s;"
      />
      <animate
        id="animation2"
        attributeName="opacity"
        from="0.5"
        to="0"
        dur="1s"
        begin="1s; 3s;"
        end="2s; 4s;"
      />
```

Then I try to restart the animation with the following code:

```
document.querySelectorAll("animate").forEach(element => {
  if ('beginElement' in element) {
    element.beginElementAt(0);
  }
  console.log("Element time: " + element.getCurrentTime());
});
```

Unfortunately, the animation does not work and I notice that the timer is not being reset. This is running in the latest version of Google Chrome in Windows 10. Any ideas what would have gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: it would be nice to see a working example ti understand what you want to achieve. Observations: 1. apparently you are using 2 elements `<animate>` animating the same opacity: why? 2. Instead of from and to attributes you can use a list of `values`. 3. I would use beginElement with an event listener. Otherwise you are beginning the new animation on the same moment when the animation is starting, so you won't notice any difference

Comment: Hi, good question. This is a flashing animation that last for only 4 seconds. After that, I am trying to trigger the animation again on mouseup event with the beginelement code. What i don’t understand is that it is supposed to reset the timer but apparently its not.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem, thanks to the tip provided by enxaneta, using values work.

```
      <animate id="animation1" attributeName="opacity"
      values="0;0.5;0" dur="2s"
      repeatCount="2"/>
```